# Find words in text, php

Tags: php

How to resolve this problem:

Write a PHP program that finds the **word in a text**.
The suffix is separated from the text by a pipe.
For example: **suffix|SOME_TEXT**;

**input: text|lorem ips llfaa Loremipsumtext.
output: Loremipsumtext**

My code is this, but logic maybe is wrong:

```
$mystring = fgets(STDIN);
$find   = explode('|', $mystring);
$pos = strpos($find, $mystring);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$find' was not found in the string '$mystring'.";
}
else {
    echo "The string '$find' was found in the string '$mystring',";
    echo " and exists at position $pos.";
}
```

Comment: in your code $find is an array, strpos expects a string

Comment: find is an array. you can't use array with echo. you can use print_r or var_dump. another way is foreach loop.

Comment: You should be searching `$find[1]`, it contains the part of the input after the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode()` returns an array, so you need to use `$find[0]` for the suffix, and `$find[1]` for the text. So it should be:

```
$suffix = $find[0];
$text = $find[1];
$pos = strpos($text, $suffix);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$suffix' was not found in '$text'.";
} else {
    echo "The string '$suffix' was found in '$text', ";
    echo " and exists at position $pos.";
}
```

However, this returns the position of the suffix, not the word containing it. It also doesn't check that the suffix is at the end of the word, it will find it anywhere in the word. If you want to match words rather than just strings, a regular expression would be a better method.

```
$suffix = $find[0];
$regexp = '/\b[a-z]*' . $suffix . '\b/i';
$text = $find[1];
$found = preg_match($regexp, $text, $match);

if ($found) {
    echo echo "The suffix '$suffix' was found in '$text', ";
    echo " and exists in the word '$match[0]'.";
} else {
    echo "The suffix '$suffix' was not found in '$text'.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but how to show the "find" word, echo 'find' word ?

Comment: `$match[0]` contains the word.

Comment: Thanks, I got it ; )

Comment: You could use `preg_match_all()` to find all matches instead of just one match.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try (y)